# How to set TTL for race conditions in Redis cache

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis for cache in my application which is configured in spring beans, spring-data-redis 1.7.1, jedis 2.9.0.
I would like to know how to set the race condition ttl in the configuration.

Please comment if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Explain what do you mean by race condition and race condition ttl.

Comment: Race condition ttl is to lock down the key for recalculation when key reaches expiry time . It prevents multiple processes from trying to simultaneously repopulate the same key .

Comment: https://github.com/anujdas/atomic_redis_cache

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want the same as that Ruby repo, but in Java.
For that case you may want to put a technical lock key along the one you need.

```
get yourkey
(nil)
get <yourkey>::lock
// if (nil) then calculate, if t then wait. assuming (nil) here
setex <yourkey>::lock 30 t
OK
// calcultions
set <yourkey> <result>
OK
del <yourkey>::lock
(integer) 1
```

Here with `setex` you set a lock key with TTL of 30 sec. You can put another TTL if you want.

There is one problem with the code above - some time will pass before checking a lock and aquiring it. To properly aquire a lock EVAL can be used: `eval "local lk=KEYS[1]..'::lock' local lock=redis.call('get',lk) if (lock==false) then redis.call('setex',lk,KEYS[2],'t') return 1 else return 0 end" 2 <yourkey> 30` This either returns 0 if there is no lock or puts a lock and returns 1.

Comment: Yeah, But its says default lock time is 30s . I want to override that lock time ..perhaps decrease it to 10s.

Comment: put 10 as the second parameter of `setex`

Comment: how to set it in spring bean configuration ...?? I can set expiration and max redirect in spring beans ... in same way I am looking for race condition ttl as well

Comment: I don't know if spring-data-redis have this functionality. You probbly have to do it manually.

Comment: I found an unanswered question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052312/spring-boot-starter-data-redis-cacheablesync-true-sees-not-work) that hints that synchronous update doesn't work in spring-data-cache at all. But it might had changed since then.